# QR Code Reader in Xamarin ios (native ios ) not crossplatform

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I need help, i am always getting null value when decoding the image(QR code)

```c#
try{
 LuminanceSource source = new  RGBLuminanceSource(byteArrayImage, width, height);

 BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
 Console.WriteLine(bitmap);
 // QRCodeReader reader = new QRCodeReader();
 //BarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader();
 BarcodeReaderGeneric reader = new BarcodeReaderGeneric();
                Result result;
                result = reader.Decode(source);
                return result.Text;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }
```

Comment: Where do you get that null value?

Comment: result = reader.Decode(source);

I even treid to Decode my picture on online decoding site and it is decoded correctly

Comment: Don't you need to initialise Result? aka Result result = new Result();

Comment: Does your BitArrayImage actually contain a RGB24 based bitmap? If you pass that array to the static method `RGBLuminanceSource.DetermineBitmapFormat` what does it return?

Comment: No it is not a must, i just changed it to "Result result = new Result();" but the main problem is that, till it gets read by the reader all the instances have values. It is the decoder who is giving me null value at the end.

Comment: @SushiHangover
the ByteArrayImage comes from the NSData in order to process it and pass it to the Luminance object

Comment: @Assegd And if you pass it to `RGBLuminanceSource.DetermineBitmapFormat` you get what?

Comment: @SushiHangover
i dont know how to pass it to the static method you gave me "RGBLuminanceSource.DetermineBitmapFormat", when i am trying to use it i get error  'determineBitmapFormat' does not exist in the type RGBLuminanceSource

Comment: What version of the ZXing are you using?

Comment: Runtime Version: v4.0.303319